# Springs ,soap 1.2 adding special characters to the content type

Tags: spring-boot, soap, soapui, soap-client, spring-ws

I am setting SaajSoapFactory in message Factory to use soap 1.2 in my web service config.
And trying to set the content type in my interceptor below code :

mimeHeaders.setHeader(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="{my action url");

But when the soap request is going through it's adding [0X9] to the content-type like below

Content-type: 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; [0X9]action="{my action url'

Has anyone faced this issue with soap and spring-ws and what did you do to fix this.

mimeHeaders.setHeader(TransportConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="{my action url"");